# Forcing a method to be non-transactional in JPA (Eclipselink)

Tags: jpa, transactions, eclipselink

I am developing an application using Eclipselink and as part of the app I need to be able to manipulate some of the objects which involves changing data without it being persisted to the database (i merging/changing objects for some batch generation processes).

I am reluctant to change the data in the Entity objects, as there is a risk that even though i have not marked the methods as `@Transactional`, this method could in the future be inadvertantly called from within a transactional method and these changes could be persisted.

So my question is, is there anyway to get around this? Such as force a method to always be non-transactional regardless; terminate any transactionality as soon as the method is started; etc.

I know there is a .detach() method that can detach the objects from the Entity Manager, however, there are many objects and this seems like a potentially error prone fail-safe on my code.

Comment: tag either spring or ejb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NOT_SUPPORTED), you have

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

> Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one exists. Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.

If it's EJB, you have a transaction attribute of the same name.

---

Anyway, instead of playing around with transactions, you can simply clone your object and modify the required data. Deep cloning can be achieved via commons-lang [`SerializationUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your use case but I wouldn't mess with transaction here and either:

- Not `merge` changes made to entities ~or~
- `refresh` any changes made to entities before a `merge` (but why would you call `merge`?) ~or~
- Work on non-managed copies of entities ~or~
- Declare some classes are Read-Only (EclipseLink specific, see [Declaring Read-Only Classes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Unit_of_Work_API_%28ELUG%29#Declaring_Read-Only_Classes) and  [How to Use the @ReadOnly Annotation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_the_.40ReadOnly_Annotation)). From the doc:

  > Any changes made within a managed instance in a transaction or to a detached instance and merged will have no effect in the context of a read-only entity class.